# Retrieve information about "memory protection"

Tags: hardware, programming

I read in Wikipedia that there were two ways to achieve "memory protection"

1. Access control lists
2. "Traits" where a SUN processor used traits for pointer and the memory. That particular processor had hardware designed to control a program by using "traits" for the pointers and the memory. I'm looking for the technique of that SUN CPU. There's nothing about it reading the Wikipedia article about [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection). I'm certain there was a Wikipedia article that mentioned it.

I don't find the article again. Is it possible that you can help me find the article or more information about the above techniques?

Comment: Both terms are googleable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm looking for the technique of that SUN CPU. There's nothing about it reading the Wikipedia article about [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection). I'm certain there was a Wikipedia article that mentioned it.

Comment: hm, what SUN CPU are we talking about, potentially? Assuming "Sun" is the company (the ones later bought by Oracle), they, as far as I remember, only ever produced the  UltraSPARC series of CPUs

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, that's what the lost info was about. First about access control lists and then it mentioned hardware technique similar to what I read about in google about marking traits:  _Addresses passed in buffers between processes are marked insecure, and control instructions using those addresses as targets will raise an exception_